# How can I make an R Markdown figure chunk hyperlink to the raw image when rendering as HTML?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I would like all of my graphics to link to a full image view once rendered (as the page layout constrains the width and I's like users to be able to zoom in). The chunks are rendered as static images, how do I wrap those in an anchor to the image?

e.g.

````
```{r "totals", echo=FALSE}
qplot(mtcars$mpg, fill = mtcars$cyl, binwidth = 2)
````

Renders as

```
![plot of chunk totals](totals-1.png)
```

But I want something like

```
[![plot of chunk totals](totals-1.png)](totals-1.png)
```

I can wrap the chunk in a markdown link, but that seems a bit clunky and I wondered if there is a way to dynamically code it in the chunk so the image name comes from the chunk name in the same way?